# get single category when I stored it as multi categories in mysql table column

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a problem in php mysql. i have a html where i put checkbox to get multi item.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[]" value="national">
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[]" value="international">
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[]" value="politics">
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[]" value="leadnews">
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[]" value="sports">
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[]" value="technology">
```

And saved it in mysql with this code.

```
if(isset($_POST['insert_post'])){
    $p_cat = $_POST['checklist'];
    $multi_cat=""; 
    $flag=0;
    foreach($p_cat as $entry){ 
        $multi_cat .= $entry.","; 
        $flag=1; 
    }
    if($flag==1){ 
        $multi_cat=rtrim($multi_cat); 
    }
    $insert_slider = "insert into desks (post_categories) values('$multi_cat')";
    $insert_slides =mysqli_query($con, $insert_slider);
```

Its saving multi categories into database column with ','

when I call it by echo it showing all the categories with ','
but I want to query that if single value are available there or not.

Comment: you fix your database structure so it's properly normalized. storing multiple values in a single field/record is almost ALWAYS a bad idea, and this is exactly why - now you can't join against those individual values without a lot of extra ugly code, can't add/remove/delete individual values with a lot of extra ugly code, blah blah blah. if you had a properly normalized data structure in the deginning, you wouldn't need to be asking this question in the first place.

Comment: Simple answer is ___Dont store categories like that___

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is a little wrong. You are storing all categories in one row. You should store them in separate rows.

```
if(isset($_POST['insert_post'])){
    $p_cat = $_POST['checklist'];
    $multi_cat=""; 
    $flag=0;
    foreach($p_cat as $entry){ 
        $multi_cat .= "('" . $entry . "'),"; 
        $flag=1; 
    }
    if($flag==1){ 
        $multi_cat=rtrim($multi_cat,','); 
        $insert_slider = "insert into desks(post_categories) 
         values $multi_cat";
        $insert_slides =mysqli_query($con, $insert_slider);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from desks where instr(post_categories,',')<1;
```

tells you how many rows are there with single category